# Laravel use Locale Code for Language Prefix

Tags: laravel, localization, routes, locale, laravel-routing

What's the simplest way to use a prefix for the language (en, de, fr,...) on my URLS. It should also not throw an error when no prefix is set, then it should fallback to french.

Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a package that does this for you. I use mcamara/laravel-localization (https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization), but waavi/translation is pretty good too (https://github.com/Waavi/translation)